# Show Case library android

Tags: android

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) to show the main features of the app, currently I'm using shared preferences variable like this,

```
1- After installation I set a SharedPreferences variable x to 0
2- First time the user opens the main activity I check the variable x, if it 0 I use ShowCase
view and set x to 1
3- Now every time the user opens the app I will check x, if it's 1 I skip the ShowCase view
```

I'm new in Android and I'm not if it's good idea to check SharedPreferences on the main thread every time the app is opened, any one thinks I should be doing something else instead? or is this good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's absolutely ok. Of course it depends on time of retrieving of `x` variable from `SharedPreferences`. I suppose if you save few million variables in `SharedPreferences` then time of retrieving will significantly grow and user will notice it.

When you think about performance just test your case because general recommendations could not work in particular case.